# Excel LOOKUP and INDEX-Match formulas

Tags: excel, lookup

I have got a table with three columns, x, z and t. What I am trying to do is to reorganize it in a way I have t values for each x-z coordinates, as seen below:

[image: have a bunch of x coordinates, while z are limited]

like we see: x values go from 0 to 0,99, and there are mainly 9 z values for each x. However, for some x coordinates, only one z value was recorded.

I have found a lot of tutorials here on stackoverflow and other excel forum, so tried some index+match and array formulas, such as the one we can see in the image, that returned an error.
The formula was:

```
=INDEX(temp,MATCH(H18&L17,zvalues&xvalues,0))
```

The only formula that actually worked was the one for the first column of the desired table:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((xvalues=I17)*(zvalues=$H$18)),temp)
```

Can someone help me understand why I get an error if I drag the formula above to the rest of the table?

I need this because the data is way too large and I can't really do it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to reproduce your problem. Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Although someone might bother to enter it manually. To make the data useful to more readers, edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: As Ron noted it hard to debug without the data itself but I will suggest you test your MATCH formula first with an expected result in mind and proceed similarly to the INDEX formula.